# Any way to do this without SET Count command? / Improve code

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is a batch script that will play any streaming web link in VLC
Requires Youtube-dl, PhantomJS, and VLC

**Does it really need the SET count commands**, it just seems a bit verbose.
Is there a simpler way to do it?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /p var1="Url? "

SET count=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`youtube-dl -g %var1%`) DO (
  SET var!count!=%%F
  SET /a count=!count!+1
)

echo %var1%
vlc %var1%
ENDLOCAL
pause
```

Comment: The code is somehow inconsequent, **IF** multiple lines are returned from youtube-dl [-g, --get-url Simulate, quiet but print URL](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md) they shuold be iterated, if only one is possible/desired it should abort after the 1st.

Comment: If you only want the last item resolved from the command then of course you don't need to set a variable to each item. *It's not as if you are using anything other than the first item anyhow*.

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to use/adapt code that someone else wrote without understanding what the original code does.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly - it can be done. Here's a way (but it's not simpler or pretty)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL 
set /p var1="Url? "

for /L %%z in (100,1,999) do set "var%%z"
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`youtube-dl -g %var1%`) DO (
  set "new=Y""
  for /L %%z in (100,1,999) do if defined new if not defined var%%z set "new="&set "var%%z=%%F"
)

set var

echo %var1%
vlc %var1%
pause
```

Note: data now saved in var100+, and reported by `set var` command.

Your original entry was overwritten in your code, preserved in `var1` by mine.

ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION in no longer required.

The ENDLOCAL would dispose of variable-changes made after the `setlocal` command, so it's difficult to see what purpose saving the other lines has in the snippet you've published.

Comment: Thanks, did you test it on a streaming link?